# Why Float.valueOf("2.7") > 2.7 gives me true?

Tags: java

Why `Float.valueOf("2.7") > 2.7` gives me true?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Float.valueOf("2.7") > 2.7);
    System.out.println(Float.valueOf("2.7") > 2.8);
    System.out.println(Float.valueOf("2.7") > 2.6);
    }
```

prints

```
true
false
true.
```

If I do `Float.valueOf("2.7") > Float.valueOf("2.7")`, it returns me false.

Can anyone helps me to understand this behavior?

Comment: Interesting. Did you try with Float.valueOf("2.7f") ? :)

Comment: @A1ternat1ve - It won't make any difference. The *result* will still be different i.e, greater than or lesser than but not equal. Thats the problem with floating point numbers in java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The literal `2.7` is a `double` - i.e. the closest `double` value to 2.7.

`Float.valueOf("2.7")` - or `2.7f`, equivalently, is the closest `float` value to 2.7. Neither of them will be exactly 2.7 - and in this case, they're both slightly greater than 2.7. The actual values are:

```
float:  2.7000000476837158203125
double: 2.70000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
```

As you can see, the `float` value really *is* greater than the `double` value.

In cases where the closest value is *lower* than the "ideal" one, you'll see the reverse effect, where the `float` value will be smaller than the `double` value, because the `double` value will be closer to the "ideal" one. You'll see that with 2.8, for example, where the values are:

```
float:  2.7999999523162841796875
double: 2.79999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
```

If you use `Double.parseDouble` instead of `Float.parseFloat` - or alternatively, if you make the comparisons work against the `float` literals, you should get the expected result:

```
System.out.println(Float.valueOf("2.7") > 2.7f);
System.out.println(Double.valueOf("2.7") > 2.7);
```

Comment: May want to mention that `System.out.println(Double.valueOf("2.7") > 2.7);` works as expected, since the data types are the same. As does `System.out.println(Float.valueOf("2.7") > 2.7f);`.

Comment: I can't help but say this. You must become a teacher. :) @JonSkeet

Answer (score 1):

`2.7` is a double literal. `Float.valueOf("2.7")` is `float`, and therefore has less precision, which means it might be approximated by a float value that is higher than the double approximation of 2.7.

```
System.out.println(Float.valueOf("2.7") > 2.7f);
```

would give you false, since you would be comparing two floats.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `2.7f` > `2.7d`  i.e. the `float` representation of `2.7` is slightly higher than the `double` representation as `float` is less accurate.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the precision of doubles and floats that makes floats slightly higher that doubles.

You can experiment with the following code.

```
    System.out.println("double: " + new BigDecimal(2.7));
    System.out.println("float: " + new BigDecimal(Float.valueOf("2.7")));
    System.out.println("double: " + new BigDecimal(2.7d));
    System.out.println("float: " + new BigDecimal(2.7f));
```

- 2.7 is a double
- Float.valueOf("2.7") is a float
- 2.7d is a double
- 2.7f is a float